# How to setup a responsive margin (about the width/height from the element applied on) in css?

Tags: css

I would like to know if there is a way to set up a "responsive margin" in CSS.
Here is an illustration of what i mean:

```
<div style="width:100%;">

  <div style="width:18%; margin:0 1%;">
  <div style="width:18%; margin:0 1%;">
  <div style="width:18%; margin:0 1%;">
  <div style="width:18%; margin:0 1%;">
  <div style="width:18%; margin:0 1%;">

</div>
```

I would like the `margin` to be smart enough to undestand "i want 1% of the `width`" and apply 0% of the `height` for `top/bottom`.

Unfortunately this is not the default behavior, so how do you manage it ? Actually i am using javascript but i am trying to optimize my perfs.

Comment: Unless it's just for this example, _please_ move your styles out to an external stylesheet, and use some classes/IDs

Comment: btw, 1% of what? The width of the outer div or the width of one of  the inner divs?

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/uLra3/1/

Using cherniv's idea of box-sizing.

```
code
```

Answer (score 0):

According to this http://mattsnider.com/css-using-percent-for-margin-and-padding/

If you set margin or padding in percentage is percentage of width of parent element, so you can do

```
<div style="width:100%; height: 100px;">

    <div style="width: 18%"><div style="padding: 0 10%"><div style="width:100%; height: 20px;"></div></div></div>
      <div style="width: 18%"><div style="padding: 0 10%"><div style="width:100%; height: 20px;"></div></div></div>
      <div style="width: 18%"><div style="padding: 0 10%"><div style="width:100%; height: 20px;"></div></div></div>
      <div style="width: 18%"><div style="padding: 0 10%"><div style="width:100%; height: 20px;"></div></div></div>

    </div>
```

And in this you must use box-sizing: border-box

There is no way to width containing: inside-width + padding + border + margin

An example http://jsfiddle.net/98FGe/2/

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this html code:

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

... you can "floatize" them:
http://jsfiddle.net/3rwhd/2/

```
.wrap {
    width: 100%;
}

.item {
    float: left;
    width: 18%;
    margin: 0 1%;
}
```

... or "inline-block justify" them (if you don't want the outer margins):
http://jsfiddle.net/3rwhd/1/

```
.wrap {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: justify;
}

/* this element will force justificaton */
.wrap:after {
    content:'';
    display: inline-block;
    width: 90%;
    height: 0;
}

.item {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 18%;
}
```

... or "table > table-cell" them:
http://jsfiddle.net/3rwhd/3/

html:

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="item"><div></div></div>
    <div class="item"><div></div></div>
    <div class="item"><div></div></div>
    <div class="item"><div></div></div>
    <div class="item"><div></div></div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.wrap {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}

.item {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 20%;
}

.item > div {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 1%;
}

/* optional; remove outer margins */

.item:first-child > div {
    margin-left: 0;
}

.item:last-child > div {
    margin-right: 0;
}
```